# TOP(1) BY GROUP of very huge (100,000,000+) table

Tags: sql-server, index, partitioning, azure-sql-database

### Setup

I have a huge table of ~115,382,254 rows.
The table is relatively simple and logs application process operations.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [data].[OperationData](
    [SourceDeciveID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileSource] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Size] [bigint] NULL,
    [Begin] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [End] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Date]  AS (isnull(CONVERT([date],[End]),CONVERT([date],'19000101',(112)))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [DataSetCount] [bigint] NULL,
    [Result] [int] NULL,
    [Error] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Status] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OperationData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SourceDeviceID] ASC,
    [FileSource] ASC,
    [End] ASC
))

CREATE TABLE [model].[SourceDevice](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DataLogger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
))

ALTER TABLE [data].[OperationData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OperationData_SourceDevice] FOREIGN KEY([SourceDeviceID])
REFERENCES [model].[SourceDevice] ([ID])
```

The table is clustered at around 500 clusters and on a daily base.

[image: partitions]

[image]

Also, the table is well indexed by PK, statistics are up-to-date and the INDEXer get defraged every night.

Index based SELECTs are lightning fast and we had no problem with it.

### Problem

I need to know the last (TOP) row by `[End]` and partitioned by `[SourceDeciveID]`. To get the very last `[OperationData]` of every source device.

### Question

I need to find a way to solve this in a good way and without bringing the DB to the limits.

---

### Effort 1

The first try was obvious `GROUP BY` or `SELECT OVER PARTITION BY` query. The problem here is also obvious, every query has to scan over very partition order/find the top row. So the query is very slow and has a very high IO impact.

#### Example query 1

```sql
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [SourceDeciveID] ORDER BY [End] DESC) AS rn
   FROM [data].[OperationData]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

#### Example query 2

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [data].[OperationData] AS d 
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 *
   FROM [data].[OperationData] 
   WHERE [SourceDeciveID] = d.[SourceDeciveID]
   ORDER BY [End] DESC
) AS ds
```

FAILED!

### Effort 2

I created a help table to always hold a reference to TOP row.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [data].[LastOperationData](
    [SourceDeciveID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileSource] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [End] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LastOperationData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SourceDeciveID] ASC
)

ALTER TABLE [data].[LastOperationData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LastOperationData_OperationData] FOREIGN KEY([SourceDeciveID], [FileSource], [End])
REFERENCES [data].[OperationData] ([SourceDeciveID], [FileSource], [End])
```

To fill up the table a created a trigger to always add/update the source row if higher `[End]` column is inserted.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [data].[OperationData_Last]
   ON  [data].[OperationData]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE [data].[LastOperationData] AS [target]
    USING (SELECT [SourceDeciveID], [FileSource], [End] FROM inserted) AS [source] ([SourceDeciveID], [FileSource], [End])  
    ON ([target].[SourceDeciveID] = [FileSource].[SourceDeciveID])

    WHEN MATCHED AND [target].[End] < [source].[End] THEN
        UPDATE SET [target].[FileSource] = source.[FileSource], [target].[End] = source.[End]

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
        INSERT ([SourceDeciveID], [FileSource], [End])  
        VALUES (source.[SourceDeciveID], source.[FileSource], source.[End]);

END
```

The problem here is, that it also has a very huge IO impact and I don't know why.

As you can see here in the [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk5jvy2CQ) it also executes a scan over the whole `[OperationData]` table.

It has a huge overall impact on my DB.
[image: stats]

FAILED!

Comment: In your first code block I can't see where the first column of the clustered index is coming from - is it right?

Comment: Yes sorry SSMS does not include it into the `CREATE TABLE` script but inside the query plan you will see the partitions. I will edit the question.

Comment: Not an extra index because included inside the `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` you think it may help?

Comment: Soryy that was an error, I modified the names for the question to by more clear, I corrected it.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes because the `SELECT [SourceID], [Source], [End] FROM inserted` some how do a table scan on the `[OperationData]`.

Comment: **[Discussion moved to chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86321/discussion-between-ypercube-and-steffen-mangold)**

Comment: Can you share the estimated plans for the row number and cross apply queries?

Answer (score 9):

If you have a table of `SourceID` values, and an index on your main table on `(SourceID, End) include (othercolumns)`, just use `OUTER APPLY`.

```
SELECT d.*
FROM dbo.Sources s
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM data.OperationData d
    WHERE d.SourceID = s.SourceID
    ORDER BY d.[End] DESC) d;
```

If you know you’re only after your newest partition, you could include a filter on End, like `AND d.[End] > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())`

Edit: Because your clustered index is on `SourceID, Source, End)`, put Source into your Sources table too and join on that as well. Then you don’t need the new index.

```
SELECT d.*
FROM dbo.Sources s -- Small table
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM data.OperationData d -- Big table quick seeks
    WHERE d.SourceID = s.SourceID
    AND d.Source = s.Source
    AND d.[End] > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) -- If you’re partitioning on [End], do this for partition elimination
    ORDER BY d.[End] DESC) d;
```

Comment: The index truly speeded up the query. A second problem that comes up with it is that an unpartitioned index on such a huge table is nearly unmaintainable. On all of our "big-data" table we working with partitioned indexer. They can be maintained online partition by partition. As soon as the indexer is partitioned  the problem is the old one because he has to run through every partition.

Comment: @SteffenMangold: The less data in an index the better (as long as it has everything you need) and excluding materialized views, the clustered index has the **maximum** amount of data possible. Clustered indexes are present because getting all of the data by the key is the norm.  In this case you are getting all of the data, but you aren’t really getting it by the key, you are getting it by part of the key. You need an index that can be queried with part of the key.

Comment: I'm really sorry but there is a `Source` Table referencing the `sourceID` column. The column source is only a file name. It's a little confusing naming. For each `Source` device (sourceID) there could be only one single entry for one file `source` (column) at one timestamp. Also I cant do partition elimination because the newest `End` is widly fragmentated. Thats why I came up with the trigger solution.I think a live query will not work here.

Comment: @Rob Farley I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: With partitioning, you’ll find it does all those seeks into each partition. With the extra predicate, you can make it so that it doesn’t bother with all of them, and only does some. Make it a month if you need to.